# Remove red dot on unsaved documents in VS using productivity tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

I am using VS 2010 SP1 with the productivity power tools. While I like some if it's features I don't like the red dot indicator for unsaved documents. How to remove this red dot in productivity tools and replace it with the default star?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools, Options, Productivity Power Tools, Custom Document Well, Advanced, Dirty Indicator

Comment: Hello, can't see the Advanced group under Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: @RawN: Sorry; I missed one.

Comment: Ah ok it's the Document Tab Well -> preset Customized and then Advanced.

Comment: @RawN: I was looking at 2012, which is a little different.